# Class 'ViewController' has no initializers and make XCode crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, crash

I'm currently making an iOS application, using mapViews.

However, I just deleted a file that I realized I don't need (nothing important). But since I did that, I get the error

```
Class 'ViewController' has no initializers
```

And XCode offers me the answer `Fix-it: Stored property 'field' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers` . When I click on it, XCode crashes.

Also, the file i deleted only contained that :

```
extension Array {
    func contains(object:AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return false
        }
        let array: NSArray = self.bridgeToObjectiveC();
        return array.containsObject(object)
    }
}
```

So I don't think it's because of it.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811622/class-viewcontroller-has-no-initializers-in-swift

Comment: Seems like you have a non optonal variable without any default value in the class.

Comment: I already saw the answer, but I don't understand. Why should I add var delegate: AppDelegate ? I didn't needed it before. And why does it crash xD ?

Comment: How is the property `field` declared on your ViewController?

Comment: var field: [fields] (fields is a structure... Yes, I know it's suppose to be the opposite ^^). But I don't want to change it without understanding why. Cause it worked one hour ago xD

Comment: And actually I tried the answer on the topic link. It didn't worked. I don't have the same variables :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Nevermind, I left work, then came back today morning: the error wasn't there anymore. Thank's XCode :p